# is there a method to represent a custom barchart?

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, c3.js

i have data like

```
 total= [1200,200,300]
 A = [300,100,100]
 B = [900,100,200]
```

So total = A+B

i want to represent this by stacked barchart to see the total with a gray color and the proportion of A in blue color and B in green color , but on the same chart

[image]

```
var chart_current=c3.generate({
       "bindto": "#distrib_chart",
        padding: {
                top: 10,
                right: 100,
                left: 130,
                bottom:0
            },
        data: {
            type: 'bar',
            groups: [['A','B','Total']],
            columns:  data_test, colors:  current_palette,
        },
        size: {
            height: 400,
            width: 300
        },
      })
```

with this code ,it work very nice , but the x axis not good , how can i edit this to have a good value in the x axis

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with d3js, this can be achieved easily. The way I would think about doing this is this way.

1. x scale depending on the value
2. y scale depending on the overall categorical value. Assuming your bar height is 20 (change values as per your design)

For each data point,

1. Draw the rectangles for the component parts at y(label) -10 with a height of 8 (change values as per your design)
2. Draw a total rectangle for the total part at y(label)+2 with a height of 8

It is better for data to be in this form for this manipulation to be easier

```
const data = [{key: "First", a:300,b:900},{key:"Second", a:100,b:100},{key:"Third", a:100,b:200}];

// Select svg
const svg = d3.select("svg");

// Add a group - Generally to keep your svg code cleaner
const g = svg.append("g");

//  Create your scales & axis. You'll get two functions x & y
// Set width and height, margins for your chart

const y = scalePoint().domain(d=>d[key]).range([marginTop, marginTop+height]);

// Scale based on total (a+b) 

const x = scaleLinear()
.domain(extent(data, d=> d.a + d.b)) 
.range([marginLeft, marginLeft+width]);

//  Please pick any notebook 
//  https://observablehq.com/@d3/gallery

const dataPointG = g
.selectAll(".dataPoint")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class","dataPoint");

// A Rect for all "a" component
dataPointG
 .append("rect")
 .attr("x",0)
 .attr("y",d => y(d[key]) - 10)
 .attr("width", d=> x(d.a))
 .attr("height", 8)
 .attr("fill", "#1414BF");

// b
dataPointG
 .append("rect")
 .attr("x",0)
 .attr("y",d => y(d[key]) - 10)
 .attr("width", d=> x(d.b))
 .attr("height", 8)
 .attr("fill", "#1414BF");

// Totals
dataPointG
 .append("rect")
 .attr("x",0)
 .attr("y",d => y(d[key]) + 2)
 .attr("width", d=> x(d.b))
 .attr("height", 8)
 .attr("fill", "#1414BF");
```

I wrote this based on my understanding of your requirement. You may need to customize the above further, as per your requirement.

See a jsfiddle here.

https://jsfiddle.net/h0uctw85/101/

Comment: thank you for your response but i m not familiar with d3

Comment: Fair enough. It is the graphing primitive library which c3 is written on.

Comment: can you send me an example on jsfiddle please ?

Comment: Edited my original answer with the fiddle.

Comment: Is that the interaction that you wanted?